# Compile MLT Framework to use in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, lib, mlt

I need to use MLT Framework (rather replace current framework with MLT) in my project, but, the problem seems that there are no ".lib" files available for MLT Dlls.

Even did not find option to generate ".libs" using the usual build routine as described in MLT build homepage.

If anyone has had success in generating .libs for MLT framework, to be used in MSVC, will be of great help including specifying the steps in doing so.

Tried option to generate ".lib" for MLT dlls using "gendef" (from mingw), but somehow, that does not seems to work.